# no of users logged on in rpc

Tags: linux, networking, rpc

i am new to rpc i.e iam in learning stage i want to fin no of users logged in from the below program 
and i compiled like this    "cc samrpc.c -lrpcsvc" but the error  and warning it showing was

```
     samrpc.c: In function ‘main’:
 samrpc.c:9:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’       [enabled by default]
  samrpc.c:13:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’    [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccxyIUNJ.o: In function `main':
samrpc.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `rnusers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can u tell me in detail how to compile the program and wat are requirements i need 
note:samrpc.c is program name my program is below

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(argc, argv)
 int argc;
 char **argv;
 { 
 int num;
  if (argc != 2) {
 fprintf(stderr, "usage: rnusers hostname\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 if ((num = rnusers(argv[1])) < 0) {
 fprintf(stderr, "error: rnusers\n");
 exit(-1);
 }
 printf("%d users on %s\n", num, argv[1]);
 return 0;
 }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Check Your Code

> ld returned 1 exit status means you have undefined reference to your main function **Due to which linker doesn't find a entry point to program**
>
> > In you code main has not been defined properly your run time argument too have not been passed properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
 int num;
  if (argc != 2) {
 fprintf(stderr, "usage: rnusers hostname\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 if ((num = rnusers(argv[1])) < 0) {
 fprintf(stderr, "error: rnusers\n");
 exit(-1);
 }
 printf("%d users on %s\n", num, argv[1]);
 return 0;
 }
```

Define main properly and it should work